# Is it always true that if $x_n\to0$, $y_n\to0$ there exist $\epsilon_n\in\{-1,1\}$ such that both $\sum\epsilon_nx_n$and $\sum\epsilon_ny_n$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, summation

I saw this interesting problem:

Let $x_n$ and $y_n$ be real sequences with $x_n \to 0$ and $y_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

- Show that there is a sequence $\varepsilon_n $ of signs (i.e. $\varepsilon_n \in \{−1, +1\}$ for all $n$) such
  that $\sum \varepsilon_n x_n$ is convergent.
- Must there be a sequence $\varepsilon_n$ of signs such that $\sum \varepsilon_n x_n$ and $\sum \varepsilon_n y_n$ are both
  convergent?

I solved the first question as follows: either $\sum  |x_n|$ converge or diverge if it is convergent we are done and if it is divergent the way to prove that there is a sequence $\varepsilon_n $ of signs (i.e. $\varepsilon_n \in \{−1, +1\}$ for all $n$) such
that $\sum \varepsilon_n x_n$ is convergent is the same way the Riemann's rearrangement theorem is proved I mean choosing some limit say $0$ and adding a  negative term then positive terms until the partial sum exceeds $0$ then adding the next negative and so on the limit will be $0$ this way is analogous to the proof of Riemann's rearrangement theorem.

> **Riemann's rearrangement theorem:** if  $\sum {x_n}$  converges, but not
> absolutely. Suppose $-\infty \le a \le b \le \infty $
> Then there exists a rearrangement $\sum {x_n'}$ with partial sums $s_n'$ such that
> $\lim \inf s_n' = a$,
> $\lim \sup s_n' =b$.

(I don't know if this proof is right or wrong btw. if it is wrong I ask for other proof)

As the way the second question is written it seems that the answer is no but I  couldn't find any counterexamples or proof of this claim.

Comment: @AnneBauval I meant choosing some limit say $0$ and adding a  negative term then positive terms until the partial sum exceeds $0$ then adding the next negative and so on the limit will be $0$ this way is analogous to the proof of Riemann's rearrangement theorem.

Comment: @pie The idea of the proof of Riemann's rearrangement theorem certainly works as you point out in your last comment.

Comment: @AnneBauval It seems to me that it boils down to the same proof as why alternating series converges. The partial sums are at some point dominated by the absolute value of the summands (which by assumption tend to zero).

Comment: @GerryMyerson How did you find this ? It wasn't in my search when I asked this question

Comment: It is listed under Related on this page, so the question is, how did the stackexchange software find it? and why didn't the software find it as you posted your question? I can't answer those questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Lemma :** Let $u_1,\ldots,u_n \in \mathbb R^2$ then $$\min_{\epsilon \in \left\{-1, 1\right\}^n} \left\|\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i u_i\right\| \le 6\max_{1 \le i \le n}\left\|u_i\right\|.$$

*Proof:* Induction on $n$. The result is trivially true if $n \le 6$. If $n\ge 6$ and if the statement is true for all $k\le n$ then, let $u_1, \ldots, u_{n+1} \in \mathbb R^2$. Divide $\mathbb R^2$ by six regions each has an angular sector of $\frac{\pi}3$. Since $n+1 > 6$ by Pingeonhole Principle two of $u_i$ must be in the same region. Without loss of generality, we can assume that the two are $u_n$ and $u_{n+1}$. Since the angle between $u_{n}$ and $u_{n+1}$ is smaller than $\frac\pi3$ then $\left\langle u_n, u_{n+1}\right\rangle \ge \frac12\left\|u_n\right\|\left\|u_{n+1}\right\|$ and $$\left\|u_{n} - u_{n+1}\right\|^2 = \left\|u_n\right\|^2 + \left\|u_{n+1}\right\|^2 -2\left\langle u_n, u_{n+1}\right\rangle \le \max\left\{\left\|u_n\right\|^2, \left\|u_{n+1}\right\|^2\right\}.$$ Apply induction hypothesis to $v_1 = u_1$, $v_2 = u_2$, $\ldots$, $v_n = u_{n+1}-u_n$. Can you conclude after that?

---

*Proof of the second question:* work in $\mathbb R^2$ with the sequence $z_n = \left(x_n, y_n\right)$ without loss of generality we can assume that, $\left\|z_n \right\| \le 1$. Let $\left\{m_k\right\}$ be an increasing sequence of integers such that for all $n\ge m_k$, $\left\|z_n\right\| \le \frac1{(k+1)^2}$. Now for $k\in \mathbb N$, $$\mathcal A_k := \left\{m_k,\ldots,m_{k+1}-1\right\} \subset \left\{n \in \mathbb N : \left\|z_n\right\|\le \frac1{(k+1)^2}\right\}$$ Since $z_n \to (0,0)$ then each $\mathcal A_k$ is finite set of integers and $$\mathbb N = \bigcup_{k\ge 0} \mathcal A_k$$

Fix $k$ use the lemma to find a finite sequence $\left\{\epsilon^k_n\right\}$ such that $$\left\|\sum_{n\in \mathcal A_k} \epsilon^k_n z_n\right\| \le \frac{6}{(k+1)^2}$$

This proves that $\sum_{k\ge 0}\left\|\sum_{n\in \mathcal A_k} \epsilon^k_n z_n\right\|$ converges. Since $\mathbb R^2$ is complete then $\sum_{k\ge 0}\sum_{n\in \mathcal A_k} \epsilon^k_n z_n$ This concludes the proof that you are looking for.

---

By the way, the same argument can be applied for more than $2$ sequences and using the following claim that can be proved using induction:

> There is a constant $C> 0$, such that for $u_1, \ldots, u_n\in \mathbb R^d$, $$\min_{\epsilon \in \left\{-1, 1\right\}^n} \left\|\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i u_i\right\| \le C\max_{1 \le i \le n}\left\|u_i\right\|$$

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a bit on how you get the estimate over $\mathcal{A}_k$? Intuitively it is clear that we should be able to pick signs such that it works, but I have a bit of a hard time seeing how to do this rigorously (probably I am just missing the right point of view).

Comment: You are asking about how to construct the $\epsilon^k_n$?

Comment: Exactly. I have the feeling that it should be fairly easy, I just don't see it.

Comment: Let me explain how to do it rigorously.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Very nice answer.

Comment: One final stupid question. You prove that $$\sum_{k\geq 0} \sum_{n\in \mathcal{A}_k} \varepsilon_n^k z_n$$ converges. This shows that there exists a bijection $f: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ (by listing first the elements of $\mathcal{A}_1$, then $\mathcal{A}_2$ and so on) such that $$\sum_n \varepsilon_{f(n)} x_{f(n)}$$ and $$\sum_n \varepsilon_{f(n)} y_{f(n)}$$ converge. Is it clear that this implies that $$\sum_n \varepsilon_n x_{x}$$ and $$\sum_n \varepsilon_n y_n$$ converge too?

Comment: Good catch let me modify the definition of $\mathcal A_k$ to avoid this problem.

Comment: Even though the previous definition of $\mathcal A_k$ can solve the problem, I changed the definition a little bit to make it easier to use the argument.

Comment: I think that there still might be some issue. In order to conclude that the original sequence converges, you would need to have some control on $$\sup_{j\in \{m_k, \dots, m_{k+1}-1\}} \sum_{n=m_k}^\ell \varepsilon_n x_n.$$ Consider a case where $\mathcal{A}_k$ has $2(k+1)^3$ elements and $$z_n=\frac{1}{2} ((k+1)^{-2}, (k+1)^{-2})$$ for $n\in\mathcal{A}_k$. For the first half we pick a minus and for the second half we pick plus. Then $$\sum_{n\in\mathcal{A}_k}  \varepsilon_n x_n=0$$ but $$\sum_{n=m_k}^{m_k+(k+1)^3-1} \varepsilon_n x_n = (k+1)^3(k+1)^{-2}/2=(k+1)/2$$ and the sequence diverges.

Comment: In my previous comment the supremum should be over $\ell$, the choice of signs should be reversed and it is the series which diverges, not the sequence.

Comment: I agree with you but if you see the induction that allowed you to construct the $\epsilon_n^k$, it will guarantee the boundness of what you said.

Comment: I'd agree with you if there was no factor of $6$ in your lemma (then it would just stay bounded by $(k+1)^{-2}$). As is I do not see why that would work. For every choice of $\varepsilon_n$ you potentially pick up a factor of $6$ and the size of $\mathcal{A}_k$ can be as big as we like.

Comment: Respectively, did you mean that the proof of the lemma tells us that the expression will remain bounded? I also don't see that. The induction does not gurantee us that we can pick the same $\varepsilon_1, \dots, \varepsilon_{n-1}$ when we combine $u_n$ and $u_{n+1}$ into one element.